# Ubuntu 20.04 Dark mode isn't making the GNOME menus dark

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, menu, 20.04

Ubuntu 20.04 dark mode is not making the top bar menus dark. I've done all my updates and rebooted a few times but it won't make them menus dark.

[image: 20.04 Dark mode not making menus dark.]

Comment: Steven the modes you r changing are for "Appearance" theme only.. the one top bar is from user "shell theme".

Comment: Why did you remove the screenshot? The screenshot certainly helps to understand the issue easily. Also there's no need to add "screenshot provided" to the title itself as it's evident when one looks at the post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Display settings allowing to set a dark theme only sets the theme used by applications. The shell uses its own theme. You have to also change that to make the appearance of the shell dark. [OMGBuntu devoted an article](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/04/enable-full-dark-mode-in-ubuntu-20-04) on how to change the entire user interface to dark.

In short:

1. Install the package `gnome-shell-extensions`. This contains some official extensions, including the `User themes` extension. You can install with the command `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions` or find the "User Themes" extension in "Software".
2. Make sure you have GNOME Tweaks installed.
3. In GNOME Tweaks, on the Extensions tab, enable the extension "User themes".
4. Quit GNOME Tweaks and restart it: now, you will be able to change the Shell theme on the "Appearance" tab.

Comment: If you don't have the `User themes` option in Tweaks / Extensions after installing (`gnome-shell-extensions`), find and download it [here](https://extensions.gnome.org) and follow [this](https://linuxconfig.org/install-gnome-shell-extensions-from-zip-file-using-command-line-on-ubuntu-20-04-linux) to install.

Comment: Or just **Alt+F2** type `r` and **Enter**.

Comment: I would like to add this and am unable to make a comment. If after following the instructions provided, you still don't have user themes in tweaks, go to the User Themes link provided by maciejwww and look to the top right next to "ON" - you will see a little settings cog, click the cog and select whatever theme you want from the drop-down box (I wanted Yaru-Dark). This will apply the theme across all of your OS.