# Ubuntu dark mode: "Wired Connected" and "Wi-Fi off" components not dark

Tags: gnome, themes

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.10. I set it to dark theme by going "Settings" -> "Appreance" -> Selecting "Dark" below "Window colors".

After setting it to dark theme, it was implemented well except for  ans <something on top left of Ubuntu desktop, when on clicking, options like "Wired Connected" and "Wifi Off">

Those 2 still are displayed white, in spite of setting "Dark" in Window Color <- Appearence. Those 2 components, sometimes, create strain on eyes when using Ubuntu at night. If I set Ubuntu on dark mode by going "Settings" -> "Appreance" -> Selecting "Dark" below "Window colors", it should be applied to everything, I guess.

I tried same on Firefox browser by right clicking. At that time, after right clicking inside Firefox, dark window was displayed, like it should be in dark mode. It's same for "Files".

Then why, on right clicking on main desktop screen, it displays options in full bright white, in spite of setting "Dark" in Window Color <- Appearence.

I want them to be displayed in dark theme whenever I set Ubuntuto dark theme by going "Settings" -> "Appreance" -> Selecting "Dark" below "Window colors".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 Dark mode isn't making the GNOME menus dark](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231169/ubuntu-20-04-dark-mode-isnt-making-the-gnome-menus-dark)

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the tool Gnome Tweaks with Software center or with the terminal command `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`
2. Install the package `gnome-shell-extensions` with the command `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions`
3. Open Gnome Tweaks. On the "Extensions" tab, enable the extension "User themes".
4. Close out of Gnome Tweaks and open it again.
5. Now, head to the "Appearance" tab. In the drop-down next to "Themes - Shell", select "Yaru Dark" (which will be the only option on a fresh Ubuntu install).

To undo, select "Default" in the drop down, or disable the extension "User themes".