# How do I change the appearance of the right click menu? Ubuntu 20.04.03

Tags: appearance

After installing dconf editor I started to tinker in "dash-to-dock" to change the dock position within the dconf editor. I noticed the change in the appearance of right click menu. Earlier it was a black menu with much less spacing between the menu items. However, I can't change it back. Switching themes didn't work. Any help is appreciated.

[image: screenshot_of_menu]

Comment: Just installing it should not have done anything . What did you do after you installed it?

Comment: What is the change you noticed? What is the Ubuntu version you are running?

Comment: I used to change the dock to vertical orientation.

Comment: @vanadium The appearance of the right click menu as changed. The ubuntu version is 20.04.03

Comment: Really it is simple - remove GNOMEs Hell and install MATE desktop to get [infinite possibilities on desktop](https://askubuntu.com/a/1263992/66509).

Comment: Again, *what* is the change you detected? How has the appearance changed?

Comment: @vanadium before I tinkered with dconf editor, the width within the menu items was very small and it was dark in color. When I hovered over the menu item, it highlighted in orange, now it's just grey.

Comment: Thanks! It would be good to add that information to your question: use "edit". Please also explain what you "tinkered with": in your question, it only says you installed dconf editor. As said in another command, that can never be the cause of this change. I guess the clock menu and user menu's are also light? I think we still do not know about the Ubuntu version. Solving problems requires information. Add all useful information to the question.

Comment: @vanadium yes, even the clock menu are light. I have also updated the basic info as you instructed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The light colored right-click desktop menu is how the menu is expected to appear in Ubuntu 20.04. Ubuntu uses a light theme for Gnome Shell. That right-click menu is controlled by the Gnome Shell theme, not by your GTK theme that detemines the appearance of windows, title bars, widgets, etc.

You can change the shell theme to a dark color. That requires you to install the "User themes" extension first. [See here for details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231169/ubuntu-20-04-dark-mode-isnt-making-the-gnome-menus-dark). Once that extension is installed, you will be able to change the Gnome Shell theme on the "Appearance" tab in "Gnome Tweaks". Choose "Yaru Dark" to revert the colors of both Gnome Shell (Calender drop down, user menu, etc) and the desktop right-clikc menu to dark.

Comment: Thank you. You are a life saver. This has been driving me nuts. I am very new to linux and it's community. Very sorry if I have dragged this out without the prior info.

Comment: I am not sure how you initially got the menu dark, though. By default, it is light in 20.04, and it takes some steps to turn them black. The menu's are by default black in subsequent versions.

Comment: Really thanks for the info there. I do remember the menu to be black with orange highlights, I really don't know how.